# Problem with Expo Google signin on Device

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo

I followed every single step on the tutorial page of Expo.dev to create a login page using Google Oauth.
I get the browser to open and I select a google account but the response I get back is *
Object {
"type": "dismiss",
}

Here is my code, literally copied and pasted from the tutorial page of the official expo dev site

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    androidClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    webClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { authentication } = response;
      }
  }, [response]);

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={!request}
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => {
        promptAsync();
        }}
    />
  );
}
```